# IntelliJ and Maven shader plugin with multiple modules

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I'm trying to build a fat jar witht he maven shader plugin. I am going a bit in circles fixing maven and breaking IntelliJ build, and viceversa.

My project is as follows (I left out the plugin section, which contains the shader plugin):

1. module-a        - main project module, contains main class
2. module-b        - module, used by A
3. module-c        - module, used by A

module A pom:

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        4.0.0

```
    <groupId>com.my</groupId>
    <artifactId>module-a</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <modules>
        <module>../module-b</module>
        <module>../module-c</module>
    </modules>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.my</groupId>
            <artifactId>module-b</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.my</groupId>
            <artifactId>module-c</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.clapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>grizzled-slf4j_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
            <artifactId>akka-http-experimental_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
            <artifactId>akka-http-core-experimental_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
            <artifactId>akka-stream-experimental_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.ceedubs</groupId>
            <artifactId>ficus_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.typesafe</groupId>
            <artifactId>config</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
            <artifactId>akka-actor_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                        <shadedClassifierName>allinone</shadedClassifierName>
                        <artifactSet>
                            <includes>
                                <include>*:*</include>
                            </includes>
                        </artifactSet>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                <resource>reference.conf</resource>
                            </transformer>
                            <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <manifestEntries>
                                    <Main-Class>com.my.Service</Main-Class>
                                </manifestEntries>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

module B and C poms are similar(except for the module names)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>


    <groupId>com.my</groupId>
    <artifactId>module-b</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
            <artifactId>akka-actor_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

All modules are in the same directory at the same level. Although I can build via IntelliJ just fine, I cannot build module-a via maven, because it cannot find modules -b and -c. So in general, I can't build anything that references a local project, since Maven won't find them. Doesn't matter if I try it inside the IDE or from the command line.

Building module-a I get:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project module-a: Could not resolve
>   dependencies for project com.my:module-a:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT: The
>   following artifacts could not be resolved:
>   com.my:module-b:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT, com.my:module-c:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT:
>   Could not find artifact com.my:module-c:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]

I realize I probably screwed up these poms, trying to play with dependencies vs. module references, but **what is the proper way to reference a local module in a pom file**, without having to install the module in a repository?

I read that I should be creating a fourth parent project which has module-a as parent, and use that project to create the shaded jar, but even with that approach, I'm failing to get it to locate modules in the same project, it only resolves repo modules.

Comment: it looks like you have module A depending on itself in your dependency list. look at the artifactId of your first dependency in module A's pom--it's "module-a." I think it should be "module-c"?

Comment: Yes you are right, I messed that up when I was simplifying for posting. I corrected the post, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <modules>
        <module>../module-b</module>
        <module>../module-c</module>
    </modules>
```

this part of your module-a's pom reflects that it is the parent of module-b and module-c but contrarily your module-b and c are missing the

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.my</groupId>
        <artifactId>module-a</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
```

Just an understanding, your module's pom shall include those dependencies which you might want to use as a library for the same. So I hope you want to use some code from module-b/c on your module-a to include them in your `pom` dependencies.

---

Or you may want to remove these lines from your `module-a`

```
<modules>
        <module>../module-b</module>
        <module>../module-c</module>
    </modules>
```

considering all the modules are independent of each other in terms of hierarchy.

Comment: Thanks. So if I read correctly, just adding the <parent> block to the modules -b and -c should work? Unfortunately I'm missing something, since I end up with a cyclic reference. which I totally don't understand. This message is repeated twice (with swapped module order):  The projects in the reactor contain a cyclic reference: Edge between 'Vertex{label='com.my:project-c:1.0-SNAPSHOT'}' 
and 'Vertex{label='com.my:project-b:1.0-SNAPSHOT'}' introduces to cycle in the graph com.my:project-b:1.0-SNAPSHOT 
--> com.my:project-c:1.0-SNAPSHOT --> com.my:project-b:1.0-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]

Comment: could you update with the complete pom from each module in the question

Comment: Just did, without the addition of the parent blocks which also break the IDE builds. Thanks for your help!

Comment: i didn't get you there,does adding `parent` fails your build? and moreover what error does `mvn clean install` return on your `project`?
modified the answer, you can try the alternate approach as well

Comment: Yes, adding parent fails my  (maven) build with the cyclic redundancy error, and causes weird intellij errors. Wouldn't worry too much about the intellij errors, just want it to get it to work with maven from the command line. For mvn clean install, If I DON'T add the parent block, I get the unresolved dependencies. if I DO add the block, I get the cyclic depenency error mentioned in first comment above (I had to add relativePath)